# How to get rid of unmodified files in source control vs code

Tags: git, visual-studio, source-control-explorer

I cloned app in vs code and then I used the command line to install dependencies. everything works fine but the problem is my source control section where you stage and commit changed has 127 files in a list,[this is the picture of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5GZV.png) is there a way to clear it without deleting files? don't know how this occurred, but all of a sudden i see 127 unmodified files in my code editor(visual studio code source control) out of which i just modified two files.How can i get rid of those.

Comment: Add a gitignore file? See [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

do you just need to add the folder to .gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

make a new file in the root of your project name **.gitignore**

touch .gitignore //this is how you make files in mac/Linux from terminal

add below line in that file

**node_modules**